# Application failed code signed verification ('13) - Tried Everything

Tags: ios, xcode, verification, codesign

This is a topic that has been covered quite often but since software is being updated constantly some answers are outdated.

I am trying to submit an app to the appstore with poor results.

I have read the guidelines provided by the support team and have done the following:

- Used the ‘Clean all targets’ in Xcode
- Deleted any build folders
- Revoked and recreated all certificates
- New certificate has option ‘App store’ selected
- Resubmitted app to profiles
- Assuring all code signing identities are correct
- Bundle seed ID matches the code signing identity
- The archive scheme build configuration is targeting the release
  option
- Bundle ID does not contain any unknown characters and is unique
- Product name does not contain any unknown characters or spaces

I am running the latest version of Xcode and OSX

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32

Comment: Which error message are you getting? Are you trying to sign with a developer certificate instead of a distribution certificate

Comment: When you re created your profiles, did you remove the old ones from key chain and xcode before refreshing in the organizer? Sometimes the old certs remain in the keychain and they keep popping up in xcode.

Comment: @MikeD I am trying to sign with the correct distribution certificate.

Comment: @CodeMonkey yes I removed everything and started from scratch - same as with the provisioning profiles